# Data after jquery submit is missed "with &"

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a little bug and i don't understand why

I have a form, people submit and i send data with Jquery.

But in input, when people send a link with params &id=data ... i receive in Mysql partial url

```
My Jquery code : 

$(document).on('click', '.bouton', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
var $this = $(this);
var categorie = $('#categorie').val(); 
var lien = $('#lien').val(); 
var titre = $('#titre').val();      
var dataString5 = 'categorie='+ categorie + '&lien=' + lien + '&titre=' + titre;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "sendlien.php",
data: dataString5,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
```

Exemple in Input when people send :

I have in Mysql :

&id=5951454215454 is missed

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's (most likely) an encoding problem. You'd need to encode e.g. spaces (and all other "special" characters) properly  ....or.... pass the parameters as an object/hashmap to jquery. It will handle the encoding automagically by default.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ says:

> processData (default: true)
> Type: Boolean
> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendlien.php",
    data: {
        "categorie": categorie,
        "lien": lien,
        "titre": titre
    },
    cache: false,
```